# I need help creating a specific shape with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a personal project (i'm a beginner so this is probably pretty basic). I want to make the shape on the picture, using CSS, but I have no idea how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you! :)

[image: shape image]

Comment: Could you explain the picture ? I have no access to imgur :/

Comment: Post the code you have tried already...

Comment: welcome to `Stackoverflow`...please check this link, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: .trapez {
  border-bottom: 100px solid #333;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #99ccff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better learn polygon property next time before you ask.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img {
    position: absolute;
    clip-path: polygon(1% 0%, 10% 0%, 22% 12%, 36% 19%, 56% 25%, 77% 29%, 92% 30%, 100% 31%, 100% 68%, 93% 69%, 86% 70%, 61% 73%, 34% 77%, 19% 83%, 8% 93%, 1% 91%);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/TEIDE.JPG" width="500" height="500">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: oh wow, okay i didn't even know this was possible. like i said i'm a complete beginner and don't even know how and where to start. but i thought i'd give it a try. i'm tyring to make a chess figure (king) and this was the only part missing. thank you!

Comment: [https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) refer this link for better understanding

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: can you mark green tick for acceptance. so every one knows that this is working!!?